# Not getting full array of project while creating project. It returns only name of project

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am making a form to create a project in react.js/react-redux but somehow I am not getting the full array of project while creating a project(refer screenshot). It returns only the name of project like this(refer screenshot). Instead of project name I want the full array of the project with the project name, description, start_date, and end_date.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicu1.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCW2O.png)

---

**Part:** The code for API fetching is as follows.

```
function project(project) {
console.log(project)
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(project)
};
return fetch(`http://pms.infotech.com/api/project`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
```

}

**Part**: The code for action is as follows.

```
function project(project) {
console.log(project)
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request(project));
    userService.project(project)
        .then(
            project => {
                dispatch(success());

                // dispatch(alertActions.success('Project added successfully!'));
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error, 'error--------------------------')
                dispatch(failure(error));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
            }
        );
};

function request(project) {
    return {
        type: appConstants.PROJECT_REQUEST,
        project
    }
}

function success(project) {
    return {
        type: appConstants.PROJECT_SUCCESS,
        project
    }
}

function failure(error) {
    return {type: appConstants.PROJECT_FAILURE, error}
}
```

}

**Part**: The code for reducer is as follows.

```
import {appConstants} from '../helpers/app-components';

export function project(state = {}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case appConstants.PROJECT_REQUEST:
        return {addProject: true};
    case appConstants.PROJECT_SUCCESS:
        return {};
    case appConstants.PROJECT_FAILURE:
        return {};
    default:
        return state
}
```

}

**Part**: The code for storing the data is as follows.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../Reducers';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const store = createStore(
rootReducer,
applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware
)
```

);

Comment: What's a "*project*"? What does "*array of project*" mean? And is your problem that the API is not returning the correct data? If yes, you need to show us the server code.

Comment: Please refer to the screenshot for the same. "Array of project" is not returning the values of form-inputs. API is returning the correct data which is not the problem. The question when i try to submit form, it is not returning the full array of values of input fields. Pls refer screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to pass project to success in `userService.project(project).then`:

```
dispatch(success(project));
```

after fixing this you have to fix the reducer.

your reducer is just ignoring every action and does not update the state.
you are dispatching actions correctly but you are not getting and setting their payload in your reducer, see your switch case, you should return the new state from your case. you are returning an empty object at the moment. what you are seeing in the console is the dispatched actions log. check the example here:
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions

for example for success case you can do like this to set the project in the store:

```
case appConstants.PROJECT_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    project: payload.project,
  };
```

Comment: What does "*here*" refer to in the question?

Comment: Hi @KavianRabbani - i I have tried the same. But I am getting the same issue again

Comment: Can you add your reducer to the question? Is data set in the store?

Comment: @KavianRabbani Reducer code is already there in the question (pls check the last section/block). And answer to your second question >> Yes , data set is in the store. pls check edited qestion.

Comment: you are dispatching actions correctly but you are not getting and setting their payload in your reducer, see your switch case, you should return the new state from your case. you are returning an empty object at the moment. what you are seeing in the console is the dispatched `actions` log. check the example here: https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions